# Can you specify `logger` as dependency for a debian package?

Tags: package-management, dependencies, debian-installer

I have following dependencies for `debian/control` file,

```
Depends: python3, logger
```

When I try to install (`apt install`) it on Ubuntu22.04, I get

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 <package-name> : Depends: logger but it is not installable
```

I get similar result from `dpkg -i <package-name>`,

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of <package-name>:
 <package-name> depends on logger; however:
  Package logger is not installed.
```

Does it mean that `logger` always comes with Ubuntu?

Comment: No, it means logger is always installed *with that package*. That is how dependencies work.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc. *This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*

Answer (score 0):

I found out that `logger` is an executable and is provided by `bsdutils` by running,

```
$ dpkg -S `which logger`
bsdutils: /usr/bin/logger
```

So it should be `Depends: bsdutils`.